# Is there an efficient encrypted data structure that supports range search but doesn't reveal order

Tags: database, encryption, indexing

Is there a fast, encrypted data structure that supports range search but doesn't reveal order?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a probabilistic spatial filter with secret permutations supports range (and bounding and intersection) search but doesn't reveal order. It can do this because the hierarchy of the spatial subdivisions is maintained by the filter, but all subdivisions have secret ordering.